# Printing lines in a file, filtering by the first column

Tags: python, csv, bitwise

I am setting up a project which involves a lot of data analysis, each data point represented by a line in a large text file. In order to test for certain types of data, I added a tag to each line (It needs to remain in one file, though). Now I want to conveniently choose which type of data I want to include, currently I have five types (`positive`, `negative`, `neutral`, `objective`, `objective-OR-neutral`). Coming from C, I wrote my `parse(filename)` function the following way:

```
# parsing.py
# flags
POS = 1
NEG = 2
NEU = 4
OBJ = 8
OON = 16

# 'flag transformation dictionary'
ftd = {u'positive': POS,
       u'negative': NEG,
       u'neutral': NEU,
       u'objective': OBJ,
       u'objective-OR-neutral': OON}

# Read flagged data from file, return only entries with the right flag.
# Each line is: <flag><\t><content>
def parse(f_loc, flags=0):
    for line in open(f_loc):
        flag, content = line.strip().split('\t')
        if ftd[flag] & flags:  # this wouldn't be as pretty with kwargs
            yield content
```

Using this utility function somewhere else would then look like this:

```
# parsing_test.py
from parsing import parse, POS, NEG, NEU, OBJ, OON

# print all data flagged as 'positive', 'negative', or 'neutral'
for entry in parse('file.txt', POS | NEG | NEU):
    print(entry)

# print all data, no matter the flag
for entry in parse('file.txt', POS | NEG | NEU | OBJ | OON):
    print(entry)
```

I am just starting this project and am very conscious about good style (especially intuitiveness, extendability, robustness, and speed), so I would appreciate any criticism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one thing, in a bitmasking expression it reads much more naturally if you put the "variable" on the left and the "constant mask" on the right. In the same way that we write `if x == 0` instead of `if 0 == x`, we also prefer to write `if x & mask` rather than `if mask & x`.

```
def parse(f_loc, flags=0):
    for line in open(f_loc):
        flag, content = line.strip().split('\t')
        if flags & ftd.get(flag, 0):
            yield content
```

However, your bitflag identifiers `POS`, `NEU`, `OON`, etc., are pretty much unreadable, especially given that *you already have English names for them* right there in the source file! If I were you, I'd replace the entire function with simply

```
def parse(f_loc, flags):
    for line in open(f_loc):
        flag, content = line.strip().split('\t')
        if flag in flags:
            yield content
```

and then call it as

```
# print all data flagged as 'positive', 'negative', or 'neutral'
flags = ['positive', 'negative', 'neutral']
for entry in parse('file.txt', flags):
    print(entry)

# print all data, no matter the flag
flags = ['positive', 'negative', 'neutral', 'objective', 'objective-OR-neutral']
for entry in parse('file.txt', flags):
    print(entry)
```

At this point the code is simple enough that you don't even really need the `parse` function anymore!

If you're concerned about efficiency, and you have the power to change your input file format, consider switching to single-character flags and fixed-width fields so that you don't need to `strip` or `split` your lines.

```
def parse(f_loc, flags):
    for line in open(f_loc):
        if line[0] in flags:
            yield line[:1].rstrip()

# print all data flagged as 'positive', 'negative', or 'neutral'
for entry in parse('file.txt', "+-n"):
    print(entry)

# print all data, no matter the flag
for entry in parse('file.txt', "+-noO"):
    print(entry)
```

---

One last thing: IMHO

```
from parsing import parse
... parse('file.txt', flags) ...
```

is generally inferior to

```
import parsing
... parsing.parse('file.txt', flags) ...
```

This way, when I see the call site, my first question isn't "what is `parse`?" (could be a local variable, a function in this file, etc. etc.); instead, my first question is "what is `parsing`?" (which I generally know off the top of my head because it's the name of a module, and it's easy to remember all the modules I'm using). Plus, if I ever need to use any other functions out of `parsing`, they're all at my fingertips:

```
from parsing import parse, NEU  # change
... parse('file.txt', NEU) ...  # change
```

is inferior to

```
import parsing                  # no change needed
... parsing.parse('file.txt', parsing.NEU) ...  # change
```

Comment: Assigning names to literals, eg. `POSITIVE = 'positive'`, is a good idea because Python will then be able to catch typos.

Comment: True. But that's also an excellent reason to dispense with the names altogether and just use `"+-noO"`, if you have the option.

Comment: Thank you. I adapted everything except the change to a list of flags. Not because I don't like it, but at a later stage I need the flags as numbers, and (without knowing it) implementing them as binary values saved me some hassle.